# What does DataDirectory mean? Any other things like it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I see some connection string like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataAccessExamples.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

- How could I determine where the **DataDirectory** is?
- What does the "**|**" symbol mean?
- What's the official name of things like DataDirectory? I have seen **substitution string** or **macro**? Or anything else?
- Is there any other things like DataDirectory?
- Where can I find a complete reference list for them?

Comment: My question is only slightly similar to that one. Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet to see if the `DataDirectory` value is defined in the current AppDomain:

```
string dataDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") as string;
```

The `DataDirectory` data value is essentially a "special" value that refers to a directory that is used to store local data for applications, such as with SQL LocalDB and SQL Compact Edition.

The pipes are just used as special delimiters to distinguish the `DataDirectory` AppDomain data value from a filesystem directory named `DataDirectory`.

Various other such values can be found documented on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getdata.aspx) for the method.